# Is there a way to calculate probability of detection for two separate datasets that have different ranges?

Tags: r, statistics

I have two different datasets, one with values ranging from 0 to 1(estimated) and the other from -2 to 2(observed). I want to know when values are equal to or less than 0.4 in the estimated dataset and when values are greater than 1 in the observed dataset. The datasets are also of differing lengths. Probability of detection may not be the best choice for this...if not what would be?

My data looks like this:

Estimated data (df1) `df1<-data.frame(est=c(0.2327,0.2443,0.4988, 0.5823))`

Observed Data (df2) `df2<-data.frame(obs=c(0.57,0.24,1.62))`

I have tried a few different functions I found on similar questions but without luck.

Thank you for any help you can provide!!

Comment: The question is unclear. Are the observations paired? If so, why differing lengths? Perhaps some are NA?

Comment: Sorry about that. The observations are related to drought detection. One metric the higher the value the more intense the drought, and the other dataset the lower the value the more intense the drought. The reason for differing lengths is the observation dates within the data.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the clarification. In that case, does the answer provided by Phoenix help? Assuming you can filter both tables independently, and join them back using a common key of observation dates, it should be good to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

filtered_df1 <- df1 %>% filter(est <= 0.4)
filtered_df2 <- df2 %>% filter(obs > 1)
```